What is `optimizeWrite=True` advantage over explicit `repartition(n)/coalesce(n)` in Delta Lake?
Starting from 3.1.0, Delta Lake driver provides new optimizeWrite mode. From the docs

Note
You might have code that runs coalesce(n) or repartition(n) just before you write out your data to control the number of files written. Optimized writes eliminates the need to use this pattern.

Do I understand correctly that this new mode does not bring any performance benefits over explicit coalesce(n) or repartition(n), and just enforces "merge many small files into larger one" approach in case you forgot to add explicit coalesce/repartition before write?
In other words - has someone tested performance of optimizeWrite vs explicit coalesce/repartition? Was better/worse/the same?
